# Unhandled Exception: type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<dynamic>' Flutter dart

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, dart-pub, flutter-listview

Am getting this error in flutter, dart.

> '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type
> 'List'

The Model used is,

```
import 'dart:convert';

Areas areasFromJson(String str) => Areas.fromJson(json.decode(str));

String areasToJson(Areas data) => json.encode(data.toJson());

class Areas {
  bool success;
  Data data;
  String message;

  Areas({
    required this.success,
    required this.data,
    required this.message,
  });

  factory Areas.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Areas(
    success: json["success"],
    data: Data.fromJson(json["data"]),
    message: json["message"],
  );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    "success": success,
    "data": data.toJson(),
    "message": message,
  };
}

class Data {
  List<Area> areas;

  Data({
    required this.areas,
  });

  factory Data.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Data(
    areas: List<Area>.from(json["areas"].map((x) => Area.fromJson(x))),
  );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    "areas": List<dynamic>.from(areas.map((x) => x.toJson())),
  };
}

class Area {
  int id;
  String name;
  String state;
  String country;
  DateTime createdAt;
  DateTime updatedAt;

  Area({
    required this.id,
    required this.name,
    required this.state,
    required this.country,
    required this.createdAt,
    required this.updatedAt,
  });

  factory Area.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Area(
    id: json["id"],
    name: json["name"],
    state: json["state"],
    country: json["country"],
    createdAt: DateTime.parse(json["created_at"]),
    updatedAt: DateTime.parse(json["updated_at"]),
  );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    "id": id,
    "name": name,
    "state": state,
    "country": country,
    "created_at": createdAt.toIso8601String(),
    "updated_at": updatedAt.toIso8601String(),
  };
}
```

In the controller file, trying to call the GET API via override init  @override

> void initState() {
> getAreas();
> super.initState();   }

```
Future<List<Areas>> getAreas() async {
    final Map<String, String> headers = {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Authorization': 'Bearer $accessToken',
    };

    final response = await http.get(Uri.parse('https://idonor.ae/api/get-areas'),
        headers: headers);
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      final List result = json.decode(response.body);
      print(result);
      final String responseString = response.body;
      final Areas getAreas = Areas.fromJson(json.decode(responseString));
      print(getAreas.data.areas);
      return result.map((e) => Areas.fromJson(e)).toList();
    } else {
      throw Exception('Failed to load data');
    }
  }
```

I just looking to get the data and show in text data when the page loads.

Answer (score 0):

excuse me.

this is json object **json.decode(response.body);** not List

```
final List result = json.decode(response.body);
print(result);
```

delete to this lines

Answer (score 0):

You already have the function to get area from json string `areasFromJson`.

If you believe that the `response.body` is `String` type, simply pass `response.body` to `areasFromJson`, otherwise convert it to json string using `json.encode(response.body))`.

Example:

```
final Areas getAreas = areasFromJson(json.encode(response.body));
```

Answer (score 0):

**If you are trying to assign a map to a list, use the List.from constructor to create a list from the map values.**

**For example:**

```
Map<String, dynamic> myMap = {'key1': 'value1', 'key2': 'value2'};

List<dynamic> myList = List.from(myMap.values);

print(myList); // Output: [value1, value2]
```